# Php Paging not working on form submit

Tags: php, html, pagination

I am new to php and here i have a form with 2 dropdown boxes and a submit button. Value of these boxes comes from my database. 
 My html code is

```
<form method = "post" id = "myform" >
<select name='country'>
<option value="all" <?php if($item == 'all'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >--Select--</option>
<option value="India" <?php if($item == 'india'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >India</option>
<option value="USA" <?php if($item == 'USA'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >USA/option>
</select>

<select name='code'>
<option value="all" <?php if($item == 'all'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >--Select--</option>
<option value="12" <?php if($item == '12'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >12</option>
<option value="345" <?php if($item == '345'): echo "selected='selected'"; endif; ?> >345</option>
</select>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" >
```

With submit button i am fetching the records from my database. Its working fine now. I would like to add paging in this form and i tried something like

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_REQUEST['country'])  )
    {

    // code......

//paging query**
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) 
   {            
    echo "<td><a href='test.php?page=".$i."&country=$country&code=$code'>".$i."</a><td> ";          

};

    }
    ?>
```

if i try the above the values are displaying for the first page but the second page is empty. And also i would like to keep the dropdown value as selected throughout the paging. I surfed google but cannot able to find it.  I followed [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm)  tutorial for paging. Please help me in achiving this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass that filter condition throw pagination link also.
For that, you should change your form method to POST. 
And in your pagination code, Add that filter value to the links with same name as given in form.

**Edited**
change your form method to GET

Comment: i added my paging query above.. i did the same as u mentioned. If i am wrong give me an sample code so that i can correct mine

Answer (score 0):

First change your form methot to get, and here is a full working pagination script. 
**Please not that, $npr is a variable in which you will store total record count which you have to get from db.**

```
<?php
$npr = $total_records;  //which should be get from db using count query
$rowsPerPage = 15;  //total number of records you want to display on page

// -------how many pages we have when using paging?-------
$maxPage = ceil($npr/$rowsPerPage);

$get_var = $_GET;
if(isset($get_var['page']))
    unset($get_var['page']);

$get_param = http_build_query($get_var);

// -------print the link to access each page-------
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$nav  = '';

if ($pageNum - 2 < 1) {

    $pagemin = 1;
    $sg=1;

} else {
    $sg=0;
    $pagemin = $pageNum - 2;

}

if ($pageNum + 2 > $maxPage) {

    $pagemax = $maxPage;
    $qg=1;
} else {
    $qg=0;
    $pagemax = $pageNum + 2;

}


for($page = $pagemin; $page <= $pagemax; $page++)
{
    if ($page == $pageNum)
    {
        $nav .= "<li><a style='color:#000;'> $page </a></li>"; // no need to create a link to current page
    }
    else
    {
        $nav .= "<li><a href=\"$self?page=$page&$get_param\">$page</a></li>";
    }
}




if ($pageNum > 1)
{
    $page  = $pageNum - 1;
    $prev  = "<a href=\"$self?page=$page&$get_param\">[Prev]</a>";

    $first = "<a href=\"$self?page=1&$get_param\">[First Page]</a> ";
}
else
{
    $prev  = '&nbsp;'; // we're on page one, don't print previous link
    $first = '&nbsp;'; // nor the first page link
}

if ($pageNum < $maxPage)
{
    $page = $pageNum + 1;
    $next = " <a href=\"$self?page=$page&$get_param\">[Next]</a>";

    $last = "<a href=\"$self?page=$maxPage&$get_param\">[Last Page]</a> ";
}
else
{
    $next = '&nbsp;'; // we're on the last page, don't print next link
    $last = '&nbsp;'; // nor the last page link
}

// print the navigation link


if(($sg==1)&&($qg==1))
{
    //$pag = '<li>'.$first .'</li><li>'. $prev.'</li>'.$nav.'<li>'.$next .'</li>  <li>'.  $last.'</li>';
    $pag = '<li>'.$first .'</li><li>'. $prev.'</li>'.$nav.'<li>'.$next .'</li>  <li>'.  $last.'</li>';
}
else
{  if(($sg==1)&&($qg==0))
{
    $pag = $nav.'<li>'.$next .'</li>  <li>'.  $last.'</li>';
}else
{if(($sg==0)&&($qg==0))
{$pag ='<li>'.$first .'</li><li>'. $prev.'</li>'.$nav.'<li>'.$next .'</li>  <li>'.  $last.'</li>';
}

else{
    if(($sg==0)&&($qg==1))
    {
        $pag = '<li>'.$first .'</li><li>'. $prev.'</li>'.$nav.'<li>'.$next .'</li>  <li>'.  $last.'</li>';
    }
}
}
}

if($rowsPerPage>=$npr){
    $pag='';
}

?>
```